# PHP output happening before Header output. Can I trace where echo is being called in PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, header, echo

I have a strange situation in my PHP code where I want to send an error Header back to the client.  It has worked for months with no problem.  Until now.

I've looked at the result being returned in my client-side Ajax calls.  In situations where an error header should be returned with responseText containing the error text, I instead get status==200 and the response text contains the expected error message -- prepended by a number of spaces.

What appears to be happening is that some sort of ouput is occurring before the header is sent, which clobbers the header.

My PHP code does not produce HTML, and does not conditionally execute HTML at any time.  The only output method is through echo calls.

Therefore, I'm trying to figure out if there is a way of tracing where the ouput comes from, including the possibility of tracing echo calls if and when they occur.

In my tests, everything is caught in an exception I trigger when something goes wrong:

```
<?php
...
catch (ServiceException $err) {
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    log_error("Before header, ob contains: '" . ob_get_contents() . "'");
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    echo 'Generic error message';
    log_error("After Error, ob contains: '" . ob_get_contents() . "'");
    ob_end_flush();
}
```

The above output shows me that the output buffer is empty before the header is called, and then just before it is flushed it contains the error message and no preceeding spaces. The response I get on the client side is a status of 200 and responseText of `"                                Generic error message"`.

For completeness, here is my utility log_error function:

```
function log_error($str) {
    error_log($str . "\n", 0);
}
```

Any ideas on this?  I'm also open for any other suggestions to resolve my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: For the sake of just trying things out replace ' with " and see what happens.

Comment: Are there any outputs or `session_start()` or anything like that in the `...` area above?

Comment: Also, what change occurred between when it was working and now? No updates to server software, config, php file, etc?

Comment: years ago I was have a space at the start of `<?php` opening tag , it might be your case

Comment: Also can be a whitespace at the end of a document when U'r using closing tags (`?>`)

Comment: try to change `echo 'Generic error message';
    log_error("After Error, ob contains: '" . ob_get_contents() . "'");`     to     `$title = 'Generic error message';
    log_error($title . " After Error, ob contains: '" . ob_get_contents() . "'");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who offerred help in the comments.  As it turns out, DarkBee may have been the closest to what was happening.  I'm posting this because it can be useful information for someone else who has the same problem.

What was happening is that I was including another .php file at the top of the file that was having the problems.  There was nothing special about that file, it just contained a few globel `define`s.

The problems began, when I edited the included file with cPanel's editor.  Somehow it saved the file in a way that generated the strange output.

When I made modifications to that file locally and then uploaded it with FTP, the problems went away.

Just to complete the test, I edited the file online in cPanel again, and the problem returned!

So, beware of cPanel file editing.  Note, I just used cPanel's 'edit' feature, not it's code editor.